# map iSCSI IQN to actual device(Windows)

Tags: iscsi

Working on a product(linux-based) which provides iSCSI(TargetCLI) access to many blu-ray drives. We generate the IQN values(iqn...drive1) for these drives which reflect their physical position(port) on the SATA controller.
Currently I cannot find a way to match the IQN to the actual device in Windows.
I want to do this because it seems to be the best way for me to match actual physical devices to drive letters/SCSI paths/LUNs. A CLI or API for this would be great.

Would be great if there was a dandy way to just do: 
get-iscsiListConnectedDevices and get output that looks like:
iqn...drive1     D:\     SCSI\CDROM&VEN_MATSHITA&PROD_BD-MLT_UJ260AF\1&1C121344&0&000000     Bus Number 0, Target Id 4, LUN 0

Answer (score 0):

Using powershell, we discovered that running:
    iscsicli sessionlist
It dumped out the **target name**, and the **device interface name**(which we use to read/write). 
Next we need to see if the Windows API can get this for us as well.